# Fabricjs selection or hover based on mouse location on object bounding rectangle for inner objects

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I want to achieve selection based on the bounding rectangle but with a different approach.

**Scenario:** If I draw object inside object, like first text, then rectangle over it, then ellipse and then triangle. Now I should be able to select the text or rectangle or ellipse OR the reverse order anyhow.
As I start hovering the triangle's bounding rect, the selection or active object should be triangle, but as I move my mouse over ellipse's bounding rect, the current object should be shown as ellipse and so on, irrespective of the order I have added the objects on canvas.

I tried with `perPixelTargetFind` and following solution [Fabricjs - selection only via border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143667/fabricjs-selection-only-via-border), both the solutions are not working meeting my requirement.
I am using FabricJS version `3.6.3`

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set `perPixelTargetFind: true` and `targetFindTolerance:5`.
Now you will face the issue for selection.

**Issue:** If you mousedown and drag on empty space, the object was getting selected.

**Solution:** Found a way to do that. I debugged through the fabric's mechanism to get objects on current mouse pointer location. There is a function `_collectObjects` which checks for `intersectsWithRect` (intersect with boundingRect points of the current object), `isContainedWithinRect` (do the points come inside the boundingRect), `containsPoint`(current mouse pointer points come in the current object location). So you need to override the _collectObjects function and remove `containsPoint` check. That will work.

**Overridden function:**

```
_collectObjects: function(e) {
      var group = [],
          currentObject,
          x1 = this._groupSelector.ex,
          y1 = this._groupSelector.ey,
          x2 = x1 + this._groupSelector.left,
          y2 = y1 + this._groupSelector.top,
          selectionX1Y1 = new fabric.Point(min(x1, x2), min(y1, y2)),
          selectionX2Y2 = new fabric.Point(max(x1, x2), max(y1, y2)),
          allowIntersect = !this.selectionFullyContained,
          isClick = x1 === x2 && y1 === y2;
      // we iterate reverse order to collect top first in case of click.
      for (var i = this._objects.length; i--; ) {
        currentObject = this._objects[i];

        if (!currentObject || !currentObject.selectable || !currentObject.visible) {
          continue;
        }

        if ((allowIntersect && currentObject.intersectsWithRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2)) ||
            currentObject.isContainedWithinRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2))
        ) {
          group.push(currentObject);
          // only add one object if it's a click
          if (isClick) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (group.length > 1) {
        group = group.filter(function(object) {
          return !object.onSelect({ e: e });
        });
      }
      return group;
    }
```